# SCSS: Pass multiple classes to a mixin

Tags: css, sass

I often use mixins to store chunks of code. For example:

```
   @mixin ui-spot-badges($ui-spot-badges: ui-spot-badges) {

    .#{$ui-spot-badges} {   
  position:relative; 
    @content;

    &:after {
    content:""; 
position:absolute;
background:red;
    }
    }

    }

    @include ui-spot-badges(myclass);
```

How can I pass in more than one class into the mixin. E.g.

```
  @include ui-spot-badges(myclass, myclass2);
```

to get

```
.myclass, myclass2 {
  position:relative; 
}

.myclass:after, .myclass2:after {
    content:""; 
position:absolute;
background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most efficient way to do it would be to pass your list of selectors as a string:

```
@include ui-spot-badges('.myclass, .myclass2');
```

Otherwise, you have to do some looping to get the selector generated properly.

```
@mixin ui-spot-badges($badges...) {
    $selectors: ();
    @each $b in $badges {
        $selectors: append($selectors, unquote('.#{$b}'), comma);
    }

    #{$selectors} {
        position:relative; 
        @content;

        &:after {
            content:""; 
            position:absolute;
            background:red;
        }
    }
}

@include ui-spot-badges(a, b);
```

Output:

```
.a, .b {
  position: relative;
}
.a:after, .b:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain the `...` in `@mixin ui-spot-badges($badges...)`? Is it necessary?

Comment: I know it's an old question but  others might find it usefull to know that the three dots tell you it's an arg list. It provides you the possibility to pass any number of arguments to a mixin.